# Angular 7 application with redux store throw errors if redux-devtools Chrome extension is not installed

Tags: angular, redux, redux-devtools-extension

I have a really strange issue with Angular 7 application using redux-store. The application is running on local dev environment with no issues. After deployment to IIS website , if you visit the site using Chrome and **you have Redux DevTools extension** installed , it will work perfectly. If you disable the extension (or if you do not have it at all ) , console errors like :
[Errors][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaVx5.png

```
  ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at h (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at r (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t._innerSub (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t._next (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t.next (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t._next (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t.next (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t._subscribe (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t.e._trySubscribe (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
at t._trySubscribe (main.072d0bbb48bb0aed1258.js:1)
```

I am not sure what is the problem here , the application does not count on Redux DevTools and I have another application (but it is Angular 4) which is working with no issues.

Here is my package.json:

```
"@angular-redux/form": "^6.5.2",
"@angular-redux/router": "^6.3.1",
"@angular-redux/store": "^6.5.6",
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^1.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^7.2.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.2.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^3.0.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.4",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.9.0",
"@progress/kendo-ooxml": "^1.6.0",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.47.2",
"adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"msal": "^1.3.4",
"natives": "^1.1.6",
"ng2-adal": "^2.0.0",
"ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
"ngx-loading": "^1.0.9",
"ngx-logger": "^3.0.5",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.0.0",
"npm": "^6.14.8",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.1",
"redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
"rxjs": "6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
"systemjs": "^0.20.0",
"tslib": "^1.13.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4" },

"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.6",
"@angular/cli": "^7.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^7.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~3.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^5.4.4",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.2.2" }}
```

is there any missing dependencies here ?

Thanks